# I cant run Python file on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am a new Ubuntu user. I got this error in terminal when I was trying to open file

```
  File  line 68
    print '[-] Failed to connect'
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('[-] Failed to connect')?
```

command

```
python 56544.py
```

I use python3.8.5

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What's your question? If you're looking for a solution, it's right there in the error message. But is this code you wrote, or someone else?

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? The script you're attempting to run uses Python 2 `print` syntax (without parenthesis), whereas your Ubuntu install has Python 3 installed. In this latest major release of Python, the proper syntax for a print statement (specifically the one on your script's "line 68") would be `print('[-] Failed to connect')`

Comment: The correct syntax for print statement in Python 3.x is `print('Some String')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you seem to be running is likely written in python 2, where print did not require parentheses. You are trying to run it using python 3. If the script is not too long, I would suggest you change the print statements and try again. You might or might not get more errors, especially depending on which libraries were used.

Another way is to download Python 2, but I would suggest against it as it has reached end of life.

Comment: Thanks man i installed python2 but i got this erorr File "56544.py", line 26, in <module>
    import paramiko
ImportError: No module named paramiko

Comment: That means you have not installed the package. What you should be doing is googling the error messages. Then go to the top link or the first stackoverflow link and if the question is similar then look at the top voted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://realpython.com/python-print/), [here](https://www.appdynamics.com/blog/engineering/the-key-differences-between-python-2-and-python-3/) or[here](https://www.w3resource.com/python/python-2-vs-3.php).

Python 3 print function uses parenthesis.

So your file must be Python 2...

Edit your file or change your interpreter...